# How to stop a value from going into negative value

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm developing an incremental game here is the link for visual reference:

https://code.sololearn.com/WF65X6DEns7o/#css

The problem i have is that buttons can be clicked unlimited times and INCOME value will go into the negative.

How can disable the button if the player doesn't have enough INCOME to click the button

```js
function buttonOne() {
  a++;
  document.getElementById("btnLabel1").innerHTML = " Units Owned :  " + a;
  income -= 500;
  document.getElementById("HeaderLabel").innerHTML = "<b> OK, good, now let's   watch as your money starts to generate slowly but surely. < p > After all no   empire was built in a day. < p > When you have enough money you can buy more   units. " ;


  window.setInterval(function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myprogbar1");
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 4);

    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + '%';
      }
    }
  }, 1000)
}

function buttonTwo() {
  b++;
  document.getElementById("btnLabel2").innerHTML = " Units Owned :  " + b;
  income -= 1000;

  window.setInterval(function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myprogbar2");
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 9);

    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + '%';
      }
    }
  }, 2000)
}

function buttonThree() {
  c++;
  document.getElementById("btnLabel3").innerHTML = " Lofts Owned :  " + c;
  income -= 2000;

  window.setInterval(function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myprogbar3");
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 19);

    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + '%';
      }
    }
  }, 3000)
}
```

```html
<div id="gameMoneyBG">
  <div id="gameMoney"> Income : $ 500 </div</div>

    <button id="buttonOne" onclick="buttonOne()">
          <b>Small Units</b></button>
    <div id="progbar1">
      <div id="myprogbar1"> </div>
    </div>
    <br /> <br />
    <div id="btnLabel1"> Units Owned : 0 </div>
    <div id="costLabel1">
      Unit Cost : $ 500 </div>

    <br /><br />

    <button id="buttonTwo" onclick="buttonTwo()"><b>Large Units</b></button>
    <div id="progbar2">
      <div id="myprogbar2"> </div>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <div id="btnLabel2"> Units Owned : 0 </div>
    <div id="costLabel2"> Unit Cost : $ 1000 </div>

    <br /><br />

    <button id="buttonThree" onclick="buttonThree()"><b>City Lofts</b></button>
    <div id="progbar3">
      <div id="myprogbar3"> </div>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <div id="btnLabel3"> Lofts Owned : 0 </div>
    <div id="costLabel3"> Loft Cost : $ 2000 </div>
```

Comment: After clicking, check the current value, if it's below zero, then do nothing

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please next time use the `<>` to create a [mcve] as I have done for you. Do not forget to click TIDY before saving - Please fix the code in the snippet so it does not give error - you need to add vars a,b,c, income for example

Comment: @mplungjan thank you. i will keep it in mind for next question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste the code with each function after `income -=num` .It will restrict the value below `0` .its [`ternary operator`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjuvoWonabUAhXDso8KHeXRD5MQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FConditional_Operator&usg=AFQjCNEyfU4zvkUJSNIonRwYQ86E1fetTg&sig2=Gxdn6z4wDpDHTtb6hHfHiA)

```
 income= income < 0 ? 0 :income;
```

**Js Code**

```
 var income = 500;
    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;
    var c = 0;

    alert("Welcome to my game. It took me 2 days to create it.  I hope you enjoy it. \n\nPlease note that you get best experience on a PC not on a mobile. \n\n Also please ignore any bugs you may find, but feedback on improvement is welcome.")


    function buttonOne() {

        a++;
        document.getElementById("btnLabel1").innerHTML = " Units Owned :  " + a;
        income-=500;
         income= income < 0 ? 0 :income;
        document.getElementById("HeaderLabel").innerHTML = "<b> OK, good, now lets watch as your money starts to generate slowly but surely. <p> After all no empire was built in a day. <p> When you have enough money you can buy more units." ;


        window.setInterval (function move() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("myprogbar1");
        var width = 1;
        var id = setInterval(frame, 4);
        function frame() {
            if (width >= 100) {
                clearInterval(id);
            } else {
                width++;
                elem.style.width = width + '%';
            }
        }
    }, 1000)
    }

    function buttonTwo() {
        b++;
        document.getElementById("btnLabel2").innerHTML = " Units Owned :  " + b;
        income-=1000;
             income= income < 0 ? 0 :income;
        window.setInterval (function move() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("myprogbar2");
        var width = 1;
        var id = setInterval(frame, 9);
        function frame() {
            if (width >= 100) {
                clearInterval(id);
            } else {
                width++;
                elem.style.width = width + '%';
            }
        }
    }, 2000)
    }

    function buttonThree() {
        c++;
        document.getElementById("btnLabel3").innerHTML = " Lofts Owned :  " + c;
        income-=2000;
         income= income < 0 ? 0 :income;
        window.setInterval (function move() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("myprogbar3");
        var width = 1;
        var id = setInterval(frame, 19);
        function frame() {
            if (width >= 100) {
                clearInterval(id);
            } else {
                width++;
                elem.style.width = width + '%';
            }
        }
    }, 3000)
    }

    window.setInterval(function() {
        if (a >= 1)
          document.getElementById("gameMoney").innerHTML = " Income : $ " + (income+=a*5);

        if(a>=25)
        document.getElementById("gameMoney").innerHTML = " Income : $ " + (income+=a *10);

        if(a>=50)
        document.getElementById("gameMoney").innerHTML = " Income : $ " + (income+=a *20);

    }, 1000)

    window.setInterval(function() {
        if (b >= 1)
          document.getElementById("gameMoney").innerHTML = " Income : $ " + (income+=b+49*b);

        if (b >= 25)
          document.getElementById("gameMoney").innerHTML = " Income : $ " + (income+=b+49*b*4);

        if (b >= 50)
          document.getElementById("gameMoney").innerHTML = " Income : $ " + (income+=b+49*b*8);

    }, 2000)

    window.setInterval(function() {
        if (c >= 1)
          document.getElementById("gameMoney").innerHTML = " Income : $ " + (income+=c+99*c);

        if (c >= 25)
          document.getElementById("gameMoney").innerHTML = " Income : $ " + (income+=c+99*c*4);

        if (c >= 50)
          document.getElementById("gameMoney").innerHTML = " Income : $ " + (income+=c+99*c*8);
    }, 3000)

    function income(){
        if (income >= 1000000)
        document.getElementById("HeaderLabel").innerHTML = "You have been caught for tax evasion. The Government will now take $500 000." ;
    }
```

Comment: thanks that did the trick -- but i have a new problem LOL -- the player can still click the button and they get more UNITS OWNED without paying for them LOL

Comment: Whats that new problem?

Comment: thanks that did the trick -- but i have a new problem LOL -- the player can still click the button and they get more UNITS OWNED without paying for them LOL

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the income is below some thresold and then call:

```
document.getElementById("btnLabel1").disabled = true;
```

When the income gets higher you can set it back to false.

Answer (score 1):

Lets beautify your code a bit:

```
var values=[
  {value:0,sign,bar,desc:"Units",cost:0},
  {value:0,sign,bar,desc:"Units",cost:500},
  {value:0,sign,bar,desc:"Lofts",cost:2000}
];

//init the dom on load
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
//assign all labels
[document.getElementById("btnLabel1"),document.getElementById("btnLabel2"),document.getElementById("btnLabel3")].forEach((el,i)=>values[i].sign=el);

//assign all progressbars:
[document.getElementById("myprogbar1"),document.getElementById("myprogbar2"),document.getElementById("myprogbar3")].forEach((el,i)=>values[i].bar=el);
});

function increase(id){
 //check if user can effort
 if(income<values[id].cost) return alert("Sorry you cant effort :(");
 //decrease income
 income-=values[id].cost;
 //set label
  values[id].sign.innerHTML = values[id].desc+" Owned :  " + (++values[id].value);
  //show some cool animation:
  var width=1;
  values[id].animation=values[id].animation || setInterval(function(){
    width=(1+width)%100;
    values[id].bar.style.width = width + '%';
  },10);
}

function buttonOne() {
   increase(0);
   document.getElementById("HeaderLabel").innerHTML = "<b> OK, good, now lets watch as your money starts togenerate slowly but surely. <p> After all no empire was built in a day. <p> When you have enough money you can buy more units." ;
 }

function buttonTwo() {
 increase(1);
}

function buttonThree() {
  increase(2);
}
```

You may increase income:

```
window.setInterval(_=>income++,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i fix the button events, if you put these it works perfectly perfectly

```
function buttonOne() {
    if (income-500>=0){
    a++;
    document.getElementById("btnLabel1").innerHTML = " Units Owned :  " + a;
    income-=500;
    document.getElementById("HeaderLabel").innerHTML = "<b> OK, good, now lets watch as your money starts to generate slowly but surely. <p> After all no empire was built in a day. <p> When you have enough money you can buy more units." ;


    window.setInterval (function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myprogbar1");
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 4);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++;
            elem.style.width = width + '%';
        }
    }
}, 1000)
}
}

function buttonTwo() {
    if (income-1000>=0){
    b++;
    document.getElementById("btnLabel2").innerHTML = " Units Owned :  " + b;
    income-=1000;

    window.setInterval (function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myprogbar2");
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 9);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++;
            elem.style.width = width + '%';
        }
    }
}, 2000)
}
}

function buttonThree() {
    if (income-2000>=0){
    c++;
    document.getElementById("btnLabel3").innerHTML = " Lofts Owned :  " + c;
    income-=2000;

    window.setInterval (function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myprogbar3");
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 19);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++;
            elem.style.width = width + '%';
        }
    }
}, 3000)
}
}
```

I just checked if your money less the unit cost would be static greater or equal to zero

```
if (income-2000>=0){ ... }
```

Comment: thank you very much that seems to have fixed my problem buddy i appretiate it

Answer (score 0):

First of all as I saw that each function reduces the income with a different value. So first of all define constant integers and set these values in them.
And about your code you can nest the content of the function in an if-else statement

```
var buttonOnePrice = 500;

function buttonOne() {
if(income >= buttonOnePrice) {
a++;
document.getElementById("btnLabel1").innerHTML = " Units Owned :  " + a;
income-=buttonOnePrice;
document.getElementById("HeaderLabel").innerHTML = "<b> OK, good, now lets 
watch as your money starts to generate slowly but surely. <p> After all no 
empire was built in a day. <p> When you have enough money you can buy more 
units." ;


window.setInterval (function move() {
var elem = document.getElementById("myprogbar1");
var width = 1;
var id = setInterval(frame, 4);
function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
    } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + '%';
    }
   }
   }, 1000)
}
    } else {
}
```

and you can handle he else statement as you want. for example you can show an alert "insufficient funds" or something like that

Comment: my issue is not the progbar but ill try that aswell thanks

Comment: also every button must reduce by a different price because that is the purpose of the game

Comment: Then just change the { } of the if statement, and surround it around the code you don't want it to be executed if the available money is less than the price.

Comment: Yes and that's why I told you define a variable for each function's price.. Cause you'll use each value twice, once in the if statement and once when you reduce the price from the income.